# Принцип работы языков программирования с сетью

Tags: golang, сеть, сокет

Хочу для себя понять общий принцип работы с сетью в таких языках как go, nodejs и так далее

Верны ли мои предположения :

1. Операционна система предоставляет api для работы с транспортным уровнем(tcp, upd) в виде сокета, а именно набор операций, например listen, send, receive, close, bind и так далее, обращение к api сокета происходит через системные вызовы ОС
2. Задача языка программирования, реализовать по спецификации протоколы прикладного уровня
3. Пример. Для отправки http сообщения, язык программирования упаковывает данные в формат http, а далее просто использует api сокета для отправки данных в сеть с помощью операций i/o, делегируя ОС всю работу на транспортном уровне

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В целом верно. Хотя иногда случаются и странные вещи, вот например [TLS в ядро Linux затащили](https://habr.com/ru/post/501010/)

Comment: Хотя насчёт «2» у языка программирования нет такой задачи; реализовывать протоколы — это задача библиотек, которые в свою очередь пишутся на языках программирования

Answer (score 0):

В целом, Вам уже ответили в комментариях.

Я просто хочу подчеркнуть, что Go  - это очень хороший пример: это язык, который развивается так быстро, что некотрые фичи, находящиеся в бета-ветке, на глазах становятся частью стандартной библиотеки.

А в общем - в большинстве случаев, поддержка в библиотеках протокола HTTP обычно настолько хороша, что Вы можете несколько лет программировать на языке, использовать HTTP и даже не задумаваться, как там всё "в кишочках". Хотя - да, есть место (мне кажется, что в Go это уже давно часть стандартной библиотеки), где находится реализация того или иного протокола.

Comment: а я все жду, когда наконец то в в плюсы завезут в стандартную библиотеку функцию `std::string http::get(const std::string& url);` или что то очень похожее.

Comment: @KoVadim-Как я Вас понимаю! Зато начиная с NET Core 6.0 вроде бы GUI на C++ можно будет писать на тех же компонетах, что и для NET-языков, без специальных костылей.

Comment: .NET core? не не. уже есть cli.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу не как эксперт, но на уровне байки. Может быть, помните, что в середине прошлого века была популярна такая [пневмопочта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0). По ней было много механических наработок в отношении маршрутизации, децентрализации.
Ее закат и появление arpanet приблизительно совпадают по времени, и между ними много общего, начиная с пакетов (посылок, капсул).
Суть в том, что посылается пакет на котором написан адрес, и его маршрут определяют routers. Что в этом пакете никого не волнует, главное чтобы был подписан адрес. Соответственно, задача упаковать изначально большие данные в мелкие посылки, подписать их, передать в сеть. Над этой идеей много надстроек вроде tcp- посылки с уведомлением о доставке, udp-без уведомления, SSH когда ты просишь шкатулку с защелкой (английским замком т.е. *открытый ключ*), кладешь содержимое, защелкиваешь отправляешь обратно. Содержимое это html, правила передачи его между пользователями -http (HyperText Transfer Protocol). И тд, аналогия с пневмопочтой мне упрощает понимание.
Что касается сокетов (i.e. разьем, вилка-розетка) это изначально и сейчас способ передачи данных на одном компьютере a-la Unix между программами. Его расширили до *между компьютеров*. Не принципиально передавать пакеты в сеть через сокеты, главное чтобы был Input/Output, просто интерфейс сокетов был более привычен программистам.